# Testing multiple variable values in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I need to check multiple variable values for a particular method.

Currently I have the following:

```
describe('Example Test', function(){
    it('tests multiple input values', function(){
        expect(function(valOne)).toBe('testOne');
        expect(function(valTwo)).toBe('testTwo');
        expect(function(valThree)).toBe('testThree');

    });
});
```

which, upon failing, returns the following message:

```
Failures:
1)Example Test tests multiple input values
1.1) Expected 'testVal' to be 'testOne'.
```

I know I can group them together in the same expect statement as follows:

```
describe('Example Test', function(){
    it('tests multiple input values', function(){
        expect(
            function(valOne) === 'testOne' && 
            function(valTwo) === 'testTwo' && 
            function(valThree) ==='testThree'
        ).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Obviously in this case the failure message is only indicating the falsiness of the entire condition without indicating which particular condition(s) that failed:

```
Failures:
1)Example Test tests multiple input values
1.1) Expected false to be truthy.
```

Is using multiple `except()` statements the proper way to accomplish this?

**What is the best practice for testing multiple values in a unit test so when/if it fails I know exactly which condition/value failed?**

Comment: Was there a *problem* with the first way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No there isn't a problem, it works. I'm more wondering if this is acceptable practice or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I would say the first way was better because it is easier to see **where** in the test the error occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the first way was better because it is easier to see **where** in the test, that the error occurred.